# my loop goes to an endless loop. How can I solve it? I cannot not enter an input in second loop

Tags: java, loops, try-catch

```java
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class h {

    /** Test Function.
     * @param args Kommandozeilenparameter 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input;
        boolean check = false;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("give me a number: ");

                input = scan.nextInt();

                check = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Eingabe ist falsch");
            }
        } while (!check);
        System.out.println("getout");
    }
}
```

I am trying to check if the user gives an integer as input.
I am trying to catch it with the help of try catch and do while loop.

But it goes to an endless loop.

How can I solve it?

In second time I cannot write anything.

Comment: The first place you should always go when you have unexpected behavior is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()).  `scan.nextInt()` only consumes the input if it can be translated to an integer.  Otherwise it leaves it in the scanner's buffered data.  So if the user enters a letter, that letter is never consumed, `scan.nextInt()` just keeps reading that same letter over and over and, because it's not an integer, it keeps looping.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I do not use Scanner, but rather a BufferedReader and using manual means of translation (like Integer.valueOf()). It's a bit wordier and takes more deliberate effort, but it works better in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)):

> Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw
> InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a
> valid int value as described below. If the translation is successful,
> the scanner advances past the input that matched.

This means that the input is only 'read' if it is of the correct type. Since your input is not correct, it will not be read and the next time the scanner will try to read that same sequence - resulting in an infinite loop.

To fix this issue, add `scan.nextLine()` (or other read methods) in your catch block. When I added `nextLine()`, it worked for me.

Your catch block:

```
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Eingabe ist falsch");
    scan.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first place you should always go when you have unexpected behavior is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()).  `scan.nextInt()` only consumes the input if it can be translated to an integer. Otherwise it leaves it in the scanner's buffered data. So if the user enters a letter, that letter is never consumed, `scan.nextInt()` just keeps reading that same letter over and over and, because it's not an integer, it keeps looping.  The fix is to simply read the input from the scanner as a string, whether it can be interpreted as an integer or not.  Then you can check if it's an integer yourself, and the input is already consumed.  Here's your example, modified:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int input;
boolean check = false;

do {
    try {
        System.out.println("give me a number: ");

        // This retrieves the next line of input, without converting it to an integer:
        String line = scan.nextLine();

        // This tries to convert it to an integer,
        // and throws a NumberFormatException if it can't:
        input = Integer.parseInt(line);

        check = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Eingabe ist falsch");
    }
} while (!check);

System.out.println("getout");
```

In order to try to help you visualize my explanation, I'm going to write out a sample input and then I'll show where the data is at each step.  Let's say I enter `abc` into the console, using your original code.  The program then enters into an infinite loop, and here's why:

I enter `abc` into the input stream:

System.in: `abc`
scan:  
input:

---

`scan` reads `abc` from the input stream as it tries to find an integer:

System.in:  
scan: `abc`
input:

---

`scan` can't translate `abc` into an integer, so it throws an exception.  But note that `scan` held on to `abc`, it doesn't just go away:

System.in:  
scan: `abc`
input:

---

The same thing happens again, it tries to convert `abc` to an integer, but it can't, so it throws an exception again.  See the infinite loop happening?

System.in:  
scan: `abc`
input:

Now lets try my code.  I'll enter `abc` and then `123`:

I enter `abc` into the input stream:

System.in: `abc`
scan:  
line:  
input:

---

`scan` reads `abc` from the input stream because I told it to read the next line:

System.in:  
scan: `abc`
line:  
input:

---

`scan` passes the data on to `line`, because it matches the criteria for a line of text:

System.in:  
scan:  
line: `abc`
input:

---

The code tries to parse `abc` into an integer, but it can't, so it goes to the next loop iteration.  `line` is local to each iteration of the loop, so its old value gets thrown out:

System.in:  
scan:  
line:  
input:

---

I enter `123` into the input stream:

System.in: `123`
scan:  
line:  
input:

---

`scan` reads `123` from the input stream because I told it to read the next line:

System.in:  
scan: `123`
line:  
input:

---

`scan` passes the data on to `line`, because it matches the criteria for a line of text:

System.in:  
scan:  
line: `123`
input:

---

The code successfully parses `123` into an integer, and assigns it to `input`.  No infinite loop, the program has completed.

System.in:  
scan:  
line:  
input: `123`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the `check = true` assignment into the catch block.

```java
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


class h {

    /** Test Funktion.
     * @param args Kommandozeilenparameter
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input;
        boolean check = false;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("give me a number: ");


                input = scan.nextInt();


            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Eingabe ist falsch");
                check = true;
            }
        } while (!check);
        System.out.println("getout");

    }
}
```

The above code runs until the user inputs something other than an integer, for eg. a character or a decimal. If the user inputs a valid integer, the programs again asks for a number.

In your case, if user inputs a wrong integer, the flow goes to catch block and the statement is printed. No other logic happens to break or continue the loop. As for why the exception happens again and again; the reason is simply that the scanner is still trying to read the previous input and the cycle keeps on repeating.

If you wanted the program to ask for an integer again and again until a correct input is entered, the following code does the job.

```java
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class h {

    /** Test Funktion.
     * @param args Kommandozeilenparameter
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input;
        boolean check = false;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("give me a number: ");


                input = scan.nextInt();

                check = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Eingabe ist falsch");
                scan.next();
            }
        } while (!check);
        System.out.println("getout");

    }
}
```

Comment: Edited the post to answer it both ways. Appreciate the input @CharlieArmstrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scanner::nextLine instead of Scanner::nextInt

```
    public class h {
    /**
     * Test Funktion.
     *
     * @param args Kommandozeilenparameter
     */
      public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input;
        boolean check = false;
        do {
           try {
               System.out.println("give me a number: ");
               input = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
               check = true;
               } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                 System.out.println("Eingabe ist falsch");
           }

         } while (!check);
         System.out.println("getout");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, Charlie, I agree with you, first solution is not good. Thank you.